# Data type name is the same as varialble name, how does this work in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

if you look at the below code, shouldn't the title data type be String. why is it called Title title;

I think it is referencing to another method/class? if yes how does it work pls

```
public class Book {
    private int isbn;
    private String author;
    private Title title;
    private List<Chapter> chapter }
```

Comment: Yes, it's another class

Comment: *"How does it work?"* Same way your `Book` class works. How are you using that? Maybe with a `Book myBook` variable somewhere? It's exactly the same. --- Besides, `Title` and `title` is **not** the same name, since Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Title title
```

is referencing to the Class Title

if you want to use the method of that class then you may have to do this:

```
title = new Title();
```

and call the methods or variable of that classes as:

```
title.methodName();
title.variableName;
```

OR if the title class is static then you can directly call the methods without doing:

```
title = new Title();
```

you can simply call the method or variables as

```
 private Title title;
title.methodName();
title.variableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Title is the name of the class. In Java, class names start with a capital letter. Here Title is the name of the class and title is the name of the reference or object that you want to create for the class Title. There is no hard and fast rule for the variable name title.

The class Title is a user defined Class. It may have several components or data types embedded inside it. For example, Title Class may have 2 strings - firstWord and secondWord, and an integer titleNumber.

Your Title Class may look something like this.

```
public class Title {
  String firstWord;
  String secondWord;
  int titleNumber;
}
```

Comment: So does that mean that when there are inputs to that variable defined the data is actually  attributed to the Title class.

Comment: like this private List<Chapter> chapter  : Here i see Chapter is given as a ArrayList does this mean there is already a arrayList named class and i am simply calling it with the inputs.